# Windows Serial EV_RLSD

Tags: c++, windows, gps, serial-port

For a program I am working on we need to sync to an external PPS signal for timing.  We are looking at doing this over serial since the signal is within standard RS-232 voltage levels.

We are using Windows 7 and C++ (Visual Studio 2010) for this project.

I can get the current code I have to trigger when there is a change on the Data Carrier Detect pin, but I am having issues getting it to trigger multiple times in a row.  I am also having an issue where I get two (or more) triggers per PPS, even though I am resetting the event before telling it to wait for another PPS.

If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Here is the code (not all of it just the section I am having issues with).  I have followed the Microsoft MTTTY example and tested to make sure that I can succesfully read data, so I know the port is setup and working properly I am just having issues with this section that syncs with a certain number of PPSs so we know we have a good time sync.

```
do {
    waitingForSerial = TRUE;
    fWaitingOnStat = FALSE;
    //dwCommEvent = NULL;
    do {
      // Issue a status event check if one hasn't been issued already.
      if (!fWaitingOnStat) {
         if (!WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwCommEvent, &osStatus)) {
             std::printf("dwCommEvent is: %d", dwCommEvent);
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
               fWaitingOnStat = TRUE;
            } else {
               // error in WaitCommEvent; abort
               throw std::runtime_error("There was an error in the WaitCommEvent, unable to sync to PPS\r\n");
               CloseHandle(osStatus.hEvent);
               CloseHandle(hComm);
               break;
            }
         } else {
             //The event has returned immediately
             QueryPerformanceCounter(&new_pc);
             DWORD modemStatus;
             if (!GetCommModemStatus(hComm, &modemStatus)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("An error occurred in the overlapped operation: SerialHandler.cpp");
                CloseHandle(osStatus.hEvent);
                CloseHandle(hComm);
            } else if (modemStatus & 0x0080) {
                //Add one second to the counter
                counter.QuadPart += freq.QuadPart;

                /* Calculate the difference between the current number
                    * of ticks and the expected number of ticks in counter
                    */
                diff.QuadPart = (LONGLONG)new_pc.QuadPart - (LONGLONG)old_pc.QuadPart;

                /* Check to see if the difference in ticks between expected and realized second
                    * is less than the number of ticks per second of the PerformanceCounter, if 
                    * it is and the new time is greater than the current counter set the counter
                    * to the current number of ticks
                    */
                //if(diff.QuadPart < freq.QuadPart && new_pc.QuadPart > counter.QuadPart)
                    //counter.QuadPart = new_pc.QuadPart;
                counter.QuadPart = new_pc.QuadPart;
                old_pc = new_pc;
                ++j;
            }
            break; 
         }
      }

      // Check on overlapped operation.
      if (fWaitingOnStat) {
         // Wait a little while for an event to occur.
         DWORD dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osStatus.hEvent, STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT);
         switch(dwRes)
         {
             // Event occurred.
         case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &osStatus, &dwOvRes, FALSE)) {
            // An error occurred in the overlapped operation
                throw std::runtime_error("An error occurred in the overlapped operation: SerialHandler.cpp");
                CloseHandle(osStatus.hEvent);
                CloseHandle(hComm);
            } else {
                // Deal with the status event as appropriate.

                //Get the current number of ticks
                QueryPerformanceCounter(&new_pc);
                DWORD modemStatus = 0x00000000;
                if (!GetCommModemStatus(hComm, &modemStatus)) {
                    throw std::runtime_error("An error occurred in the overlapped operation: SerialHandler.cpp");
                    CloseHandle(osStatus.hEvent);
                    CloseHandle(hComm);
                }
                BOOL fRLSD = MS_RLSD_ON & modemStatus;
                if (fRLSD) {
                    //Add one second to the counter
                    counter.QuadPart += freq.QuadPart;

                    /* Calculate the difference between the current number
                     * of ticks and the expected number of ticks in counter
                     */
                    diff.QuadPart = (LONGLONG)new_pc.QuadPart - (LONGLONG)old_pc.QuadPart;

                    /* Check to see if the difference in ticks between expected and realized second
                     * is less than the number of ticks per second of the PerformanceCounter, if 
                     * it is and the new time is greater than the current counter set the counter
                     * to the current number of ticks
                     */
                    //if(diff.QuadPart < freq.QuadPart && new_pc.QuadPart > counter.QuadPart)
                        //counter.QuadPart = new_pc.QuadPart;
                    counter.QuadPart = new_pc.QuadPart;
                    old_pc = new_pc;
                    ++j;
                }

                //Break out of current while loop since we have synced with PPS
                waitingForSerial = FALSE;
                //Reset osStatus.hEvent to prepare for next PPS
                ResetEvent(osStatus.hEvent);
            }
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            // Operation isn't complete yet. fWaitingOnStatusHandle flag 
            // isn't changed since I'll loop back around and I don't want
            // to issue another WaitCommEvent until the first one finishes.
            //
            // This is a good time to do some background work
            break;                       

        default:
            // Error in the WaitForSingleObject; abort
            // This indicates a problem with the OVERLAPPED structure's
            // event handle.
        CloseHandle(osStatus.hEvent);
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        throw std::runtime_error("There was and error in WaitForSingleObject\r\n");
         }
      }
   } while (waitingForSerial);
} while (j < calib_time);
```

Comment: This is better suited for Code Review SE.

Comment: when you use asynchronous io - you need bind *callback* to file handle. and program logic implement in callback. if callback will be not be called auto (this determinate by return status) you need direct call it. logic become much more clear